# When is tabular data not tabular data?

Tags: html, css, tabular

Okay, so we all know we're not supposed to use tables for formatting; we're supposed to used divs and CSS; tables are for tabular data.  But what is tabular data?

I run a forum for people who make model terrain.

The home page has a header, footer, menu on the left, and a space for content.  These are all defined by divs and CSS... as they should be.  :-)

However the content for the home page is a list of forums i.e. titles, number of topics, date of last post.  Tabular data methinks?

Click on a forum and you get a page whose content is a list of topics i.e. topic titles, number of posts, date of last post.  More tabular data?

Click on a topic and we have a page whose content is effectively split into two columns; the first contains the poster name, avatar, posters rank, etc,  The second column contains the post itself.  There are also "rows" that contain buttons to quote a post, report a post as abusive, etc.

I'm guessing that, at a first glance, most people would define the first two as tabular data.  The third... hmm... I think opinions might be divided?

My forum software is a hugely modified form of phpBB.  So modified in fact that the code is barely recognisable as phpBB.  I mention it because it, and as far as I'm aware, phpBB, and pretty much every other piece of bulletin board software I've seen, uses tables for this stuff.  So the fact that my site uses tables for all three of the page types I've described is inherited from the original phpBB code as opposed to being a decision I've made.

I also observe that most e-commerce software (including mine, that I use on other sites) uses table to "format" list of products on catalogue pages.  I like to keep an eye on what the "big boys" are doing with things like this and have observed that Amazon appear to be using divs for their product lists while eBay 'still' uses tables.

I've had a good look around the web for information on what's regarded as best practice and while there's a consensus that tables should only be used for tabular data and not for formatting, I am yet to see a definition of "what is tabular data" and specifically: at what point tabular data becomes content that should be formatted with divs.

On a similar note: there also seems to be a consensus that input forms such as login screens should be formatted with CSS (although it's a damned site easier to do it with a table).  It seems odd to me that a form with two titles (for username and password) and a couple of entry fields is NOT tabular data.  Yet if we were to design a screen to retrieve and display that information... well then it would be tabular data would it not?  And if not, then what the heck IS tabular data?  ;-)

Despite the last couple of sentences, this is a serious question and I'd like to know where other programmers draw the line with regard to what is, and what is not, tabular data.

Comment: I would say that tabular data is anything that sits in a table which will have either a heading on the top row or left column and the corresponding data within those rows / columns relate to the heading

Comment: If you're asking what a table is, then it's off-topic here. It's not a programming concept.

Comment: @Pete: I've come to pretty much the same conclusion after seeing the stuff at W3C that Nick gave me a link to i.e. that "does it need column headings" is a pretty good indicator.

Answer (score 2):

This information should be useful to you: [W3C definition of tabular data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data).

How you use tables is ultimately up to you. However, if you wish to be compliant with w3c standards, tables should **assist** users in understanding the data.

Think in terms of accessibility: if a person using a screen reader encountered your table, would the table help them understand the data or confuse them further?

A table with no summary attribute or no th or thead/tfoot elements can confuse a user.

A table containing any kind of script can confuse a user.

td elements with content that needs to be visually formatted to be understood can confuse a user.

If you are unsure of whether a set of data is tabular data, it is probably not tabular data. There are other ways to format content that are more accessible and more compliant with standards.

Comment: Thanks for the link; a very interesting if rather heavy read (in the sense that it needs thinking about).  :-)

As I see it the major points are that:

a) tables are for two dimensional data.
b) the need for column headings and borders around cells are a good indicator that the data is tabular.

Following this through with my examples I'm concluding that my displays of "forums on the board", and "topics in a forum", are tabular while the display of "posts in a topic" is NOT tabular data.

Comment: The W3C document cited does not *define* tabular data. It *uses* the expression and tells us to use `table` element for tabular data only, but it does not specify what constitutes a tabular data.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The document defines tabular data as data represented in a table...If that is the definition of tabular data(which it is), then the real question being asked is what is considered _valid_ tabular data. The document addresses that question.

Comment: No, it just says “The table element represents data with more than one dimension, in the form of a table.” It does not even say that this means “tabular data”. There is no solid technical ground for discussing the issue “what is tabular data”. It is a matter of opinion, debate, even beliefs.

Comment: "What is tabular data" is not a matter of opinion. The dictionary definition of "tabular" is ["of, pertaining to, or arranged in a table or systematic arrangement by columns, rows, etc., as statistics."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tabular). So, actually knowing "what tabular data is" really isn't that helpful in this case. Knowing what sets of data should be presented in tabular form is helpful.

Comment: Even if the W3C document doesn't contain a definition per se, it contains enough guidelines that I think I now know how my forum data should be presented.  @JukkaK.Korpela: if you disagree, is this because you disagree with my conclusions or because you have another example that you can't classify?  Clearly this was a question of semantics from the outset but I don't see much point arguing semantics unless there's a real world issue to resolve.  Is there?

Comment: I did not express disagreement with your decision. The question was what is tabular data, and this an opinion/debate issue, not suitable for SO. I simply pointed out that the W3C document does not provide a solid technical answer to the question, or an answer at all. Whatever you have decided now has been decided on the base of opinions, feelings, etc., rather than technical criteria.

Comment: I see what you mean Jukka but think it's a shame to close the question as my "decision" is, and can only be, a temporary working solution in lieu of a recognised authority being cited.  I think it's worth bearing in mind that even a textbook definition is merely the opinion of those who wrote it, based on the usage of the term(s) amongst the masses.  As such definitions can and do evolve, and if there is no current, workable definition of "tabular data" to be cited, then we programers have little option but to use our own interpretation, or better still: an consensual interpretation.